# How can I run Fluentlenium Code inside Selenium Webdriver Firefox Driver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, fluentlenium

I am having issues trying to get my Fluentlenium code to run inside the WebDriver Firefox Driver. I need Fluentlenium to execute inside the WebDriver Firefox Driver instead of opening it's own browser. I think I need to override this but I am not exactly sure how to do this. Any help would greatly appreciated. Thanks! Here is what I have for code:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();


@Test
public void create_a_picklist()
```

{

```
    // Go to Page
    goTo("http://www.google.com");
```

}

What happens is that it opens two browsers. One is from the Firefox Driver and the other must be the default browser from the goTo from Fluentlenium. I need it to run this code inside the Firefox Driver window and not open it's own window from Fluentlenium.

Answer (score 1):

By default, it launchs a Firefox browser so that's sufficient :

```
public class Test extends FluentTest {

   @Test
   public void go_to_google()
   {   

   goTo("http://www.google.com");

   }
}
```

And nothing more :)

Comment: Yes. What I was trying to really achieve was make driver use the defaultDriver. So I can run any driver.xxx code inside the defaultDriver.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Looks like I figured it out. Here is what I did to override the browser:

```
public class Test extends FluentTest {

    // Defines the Driver
    public WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    // Overrides the default driver
    @Override
    public WebDriver getDefaultDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    @Test
    public void go_to_google()
    {   

    goTo("http://www.google.com");

    }
}
```

Comment: Now you should be able to run any selenium driver code inside fluentlenium.